# Necesito dar un permiso permanente en linux para Arduino

Tags: arduino, permisos, usb

necesito saber como dar un permiso permanente para no tener que usar éste comando cada vez que quiero subir algo a la placa de Arduino.
El código en cuestión es éste: sudo chmod777 /dev/ttyACM0 y entiendo que me da el permiso para habilitar el puerto USB.

Hay forma de hacer de esto algo permanente?

Gracias.-

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es agregar tu usuario al grupo `dialout` quien es quien tiene acceso a los puertos seriales del dispositivo:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y disculpá que recién te conteste, es que no tenía tiempo para sentarme a probar. 
Hice lo que me sugerís y se me desplega un menú con muchas opciones. Como debería continuar? Después de eso doy directamente el permiso del puerto USB como venía haciendo o como sería?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué clase de menú te muestra?, este comando solo lo ejecutas una sola vez y tendrás permanentemente los permisos.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Se ve que algo estaba haciendo mal porque lo hice recién y no apareció ningún menú. Luego de ésta orden, aunque apague y prenda nuevamente la notebook, deberían estar los permisos dados? 

Gracias, espero tu respuesta, entiendo que debes estar con muchas cosas a la vez. Saludos

Comment: A mi no me funciona, para que me funcione tengo que instalar la versión de arduino de los repositorios.